# Directive to listen on event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I noticed I have added some code on a lot of my controllers to listen for an event and execute something. Pretty much this:

```
  document.addEventListener("resume", function(e){
    $scope.doSomething();
  }, false);
```

I realize it's not clean to have that same code everywhere, with the only thing that changes is the `$scope.doSomething()`.

I want to add that as a directive so I can have something similar to:

```
<div on-resume="doSomething()">
</div>
```

I tried this (but it's not working):

```
.directive('onResume', function(){ 
   return {
      restrict: 'A'
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
         elem.bind('resume', function(e) {
            fnName = attributes["onResume"];
            scope.$apply(function(){ 
              scope[fnName]();
            };
         });
      }
   };
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Putting business logic inside your view logic really, really does not seem like a good idea. This belongs in a service, or your controllers. Not much else you can really do about it. You could manage it easier with a service out of those 2 options.

Comment: I wouldn't bucket this as business logic. Basically I'm trying to simply refresh my controllers when my (hybrid) app gets resumed from a background state on iOS/Android.

Comment: That's not view logic. It belongs in a service. Imagine someone else coming into this codebase and attempting to find the code that handles this and it ending up being an attribute on some random HTML tag.

Comment: Can you give an example on how you would do this with a service?

Comment: Answered something similar to this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325030/how-to-let-initiated-controller-know-that-scope-value-has-changed/30325157#30325157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an isolate scope you can pass in a function with a one-way databind. Assuming `doSomething` is defined as a function on your parent scope, this will work with the HTML you included.

```
.directive('onResume', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      onResume: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('resume', function(e) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.onResume();
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```